# Apex - Retrieve the value of a custom field in opportunity

Tags: apex

In an apex controller I have something like this :

```
public Opportunity opportunite {get; set;}

public myClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.opportunite = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();

    //this debug work fine 
    system.debug('### opportunite -> account: ' + opportunite.Account.Name);

    //this debug gives me an error : SObject row was retrieved via SOQL 
    //without querying the requested field:Custom_field__c
    System.debug('### Custom field : ' + opportunite.Custom_field__c);
}
```

But since the first debug works, I do not understand why the second don't works and throw me this error...
How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `StandardController` in this case you need to add custom fields to standard controller in the following way:

```
public myClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
        controller.addFields(
            new List<String>{
                'Custom_field__c'
            }
        );
    }
    this.opportunite = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();

    //this debug work fine 
    system.debug('### opportunite -> account: ' + opportunite.Account.Name);

    //this debug gives me an error : SObject row was retrieved via SOQL 
    //without querying the requested field:Custom_field__c
    System.debug('### Custom field : ' + opportunite.Custom_field__c);
}
```

you need to add `Test.isRunningTest()` condition, otherwise you will receive error in unit-test

Comment: Thank you it's working, I'm not using standard controller vrey often, now I'll know this detail !

Comment: so for the test class ;) how can I test that ?

Comment: you can nothing to do with it for testing https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YmzmAAC

Comment: ok but then the custom field isn't accessible from the test class I suppose ? Because when I put it into the test class I got an error (that I don't get when I don't put it)

Comment: you need to insert Opportunity in test, and then query it one more time. Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Custom_field__c = 'values'); opp = [select id, Custom_field__c from Opportunity where Id = :opp.Id limit 1]; and then pass this opportunity to StandardController constructor

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to StandardController.addFields, which can't be unit tested, consider adding the custom field to your page:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="false" value="{!Opportunity.Custom_Field__c}" />
```

The StandardController performs a query by default based on the fields in the page, so simply doing this gives you access to the field in the controller.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was doing before, but now my field need to be tested (with a if condotion, so the value of the field is determined by the condition) so I could not use that anymore

Comment: @dou That shouldn't make a difference. You might want to share some more code; it may have been a simple mistake elsewhere.